# Como puedo sumar y/o restar el valor de un input en tiempo real

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formularios, input

Estoy intentando sumar en tiempo real los números que me ingresen de un `input` y renderizar esa suma en tiempo real, ademas tengo un botón para eliminar una  fila de `inputs` la idea es que si elimino la fila y si tengo una cantidad ingresada al eliminar tambien se reste en tiempo real

Aqui tengo mi componente en donde como prueba solo estoy tomando el valor de lo que ingrese en lunes y veo los cambios el nombre de este componente es `days.component.ts` :

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-days',
  templateUrl: './days.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./days.component.scss']
})
export class DaysComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() notify: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() notify2: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  dias: FormControl;
  dia: FormControl;
  sumar: any;
  sumar2: any;
  total: any;
  a: number;
  b: number;
  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lunes();
    //  this.martes();
    this.sumarhoras();
  }
  lunes() {
    this.dias = new FormControl();
    this.dias.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.sumar = parseInt(value, 10);
      this.notify2.emit(this.sumar);
      // this.sumar = value;
      console.log(typeof this.sumar);
    });
  }
  // martes() {
  //   this.dia = new FormControl();
  //   this.dia.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  //     // this.notify.emit(value);
  //     this.sumar2 = parseInt(val, 10);
  //     this.notify.emit(this.sumar2);
  //     //  this.sumar2 + this.sumar = parseInt(val, 10);
  //     // parseInt(this.sumar2, 10);
  //     console.log(typeof this.sumar2);

  //   });
  // }
  sumarhoras() {
    this.notify2.subscribe(cambios => {
      console.log(typeof cambios);

      this.a = cambios;
      console.log(this.a);

    });
    // this.notify2.subscribe(changes => {
    //   this.b = changes;
    //   console.log(this.b);

    // });
  }
}
```

en el html  `days.component.html` tengo  todo el `formcontrol` aqui ya monitoreo en tiempo real como va mutando lo que se ingresa en el input ademas que en el `ts` lo convierto en un numero

```
<div class="col s2 m1">
    <div class="col s12">Lunes</div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="none" class="input-date">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Hrs" [formControl]="dias" >
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
<div class="col s2 m1">
  <div class="col s12">Martes</div>
  <mat-form-field appearance="none" class="input-date">
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Hrs" [formControl]="dias" >
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col s3 m1">
  <div class="col s12">Miercoles</div>
  <mat-form-field appearance="none" class="input-date">
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Hrs" [formControl]="dias" >
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col s2 m1">
  <div class="col s12">Jueves</div>
  <mat-form-field appearance="none" class="input-date">
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Hrs"  [formControl]="dias">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="col s2 m1">
  <div class="col s12">Viernes</div>
  <mat-form-field appearance="none" class="input-date">
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Hrs" [formControl]="dias" >
  </mat-form-field> 
</div>
```

Comment: en que parte de tu codigo quieres hacer la suma?

Comment: Lo que busco es que lo va ingresando guardarlo en una variable y esa variable renderizarla en el html

Comment: Creo que estas sobrecomplicando la solucion. Si estas computando valores en un componente no necesitas notificar a tu mismo componente que estas tomando cambios, el propio motor de angular deberia darse cuenta de eso. En la suscripcion de ValueChanges puedes hacer la operacion de suma y ponerlo en la variable que quieres mostrar en la pagina. Esa variable la puedes insertar en el template usando {{nombreDeVariable}}

Comment: Logre hacer que, sume por filas pero tengo un problema cada que ingreso una cantidad de dos digitos toma el primer numero como un operador y despues cuando lo ingreso completo, lo suma es decir hace esto: si ingreso 10 primero toma el 1 + 10 y como total me da 11

Comment: utliza Number(value) en vez de parseInt(value, 10);

Comment: y cuando utilises this suma hazlo como sumador ejemplo
this.sumar += Number(value);

Comment: Intente utilizarlo asi Number(value), pero cuando intentaba sumar el valor era NaN por eso lo utilize asi: this.a = (isNaN(parseInt(this.a, 10))) ? 0 : parseInt(this.a, 10);